# Følner net on a direct union of amenable groups

Tags: group-theory, ergodic-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be an amenable group and let $(H_i)_{i\in I}$ be the poset of all the countable (or, if simpler, even finitely generated) subgroups of $G$ so, in particular, we have $G=\bigcup_IH_i$. Furthermore, each $H_i$ is amenable (as it is a subgroup of an amenable group) and countable, so it has a Følner sequence $(F_{n,i})_{n\in\mathbb N}$. In this situation, is it possible to see that $(F_{n,i})_{(n,i)\in \mathbb N\times I}$ (with $\mathbb N\times I$ endowed with the product order) is a Følner net for $G$?

If this is not true in general, is it possible to choose the Følner sequences $(F_{n,i})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in some special way that makes the result true?

Finally,  if also my second question has a negative answer, is there some other canonical way to build a Følner net for $G$ out of Følner sequences (or nets) for the $H_i$'s?

Comment: By "the poset of the countable subgroups" I really mean "the poset of all countable subgroups"... so in particular you have $G=\bigcup_IH_i$.

Comment: The, please edit, to make it clear.

Comment: I don't think that "the poset of the countable subgroups" can have more than one interpretation... but I agree that it is easy to miss  the second "the''... I have edited to make it harder to miss.

Comment: I originally missed the second "the".